# Custom page in Prestashop 1.6 without CMS

Tags: php, controller, prestashop-1.6

I'm currently creating a customized page based on Bootstrap so I cannot pass through the CMS.

I created a file `Mypage.php` that I put at the Prestahop root containing this code :

```
<?php
    require(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php');
    ControllerFactory::getController('MypageController')->run();
?>
```

Then I created a controller `MypageController.php` containing this code in override/controllers/front :

```
class MypageControllerCore extends FrontController
{
    public $php_self = 'Mypage.php';
    public $ssl = true;

    public function preProcess()
    {
        parent::preProcess();
    }

    public function setMedia()
    {
        parent::setMedia();
        Tools::addCSS(_THEME_CSS_DIR_.'Mypage.css');
    }

    public function displayContent()
    {
        $_POST = array_merge($_POST, $_GET);
        parent::displayContent();
        self::$smarty->display(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'Mypage.tpl');
    }
}
```

And finally I put a `Mypage.tpl` file in my theme directory with my HTML code.

I naturally erased `cache/class_index.php` but I still get a 404 error. Any ideas?

Comment: Be careful, it's not displayContent() but initContent()

Answer (score 10):

- Move `MypageController.php` to `root/controllers/front` .
- Change `public $php_self = 'mypage';`.
- Go to `BO > Preferences > SEO & URLs` and add a new page, select `mypage` for the Page field.

There is no need for the `Mypage.php` in your root, you can access your controller at link `yoururl/index.php?controller=mypage`. But if you want to use it, write `Controller::getController('MypageController')->run();`.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure your code cause I did not test it but you should go to SEO & URLs create new page and choose your new page Mypage, title of the page, friendly urls meta tag and keywords.

Comment: "I did not test it" is not a good way to "answer" someone's question.

Answer (score -2):

You can create a new module for you custom page.

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+first+module

Comment: Link only answers are not good for community please edit your answer.

Comment: You want me to copy the code from the above link to here. I don't think this is needed. Anyways thanks for your suggestion from next time i will answer properly without not just a link.