# Create new template for CMS pages in prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I have several pages created under the Preferences -> CMS which are ok. Now I need to create some more pages that will have a different look, is there a way to add like a different template and use the same CMS interface to do it?.
I was thinking of something like:

Step 1. Create new cms-2.tpl
Step 2. Modify the database to add a new "template" field
Step 3. Modify the back office to add an extra field to the CMS page to choose the template to be used with the CMS page

So far I have been reading about "Creating pages without CMS" like in this link: [Custom page in Prestashop 1.6 without CMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27385742/custom-page-in-prestashop-1-6-without-cms) or this other link: [Create custom page in Prestashop 1.5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14336006/create-custom-page-in-prestashop-1-5-3), but none of them seem to be what i am looking for.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for Prestashop 16.0.14:

Copy `/controllers/front/CmsController.php` to `/override/controllers/front/CmsController.php` and find the last method of the class, which is `initContent()`.

The last line is `$this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'cms.tpl');`.
Change it to:

```
if(is_file(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'cms-'.$this->cms->id.'.tpl')){
    $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'cms-'.$this->cms->id.'.tpl');
}
else{
    $this->setTemplate(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'cms.tpl');
}
```

Then you need to delete the file `/cache/class_index.php` to force cache recreation.

Then you can create files inside your theme folder like this: `cms-2.tpl` where 2 is the id from your CMS page (just duplicate cms.tpl and change filename).
Make sure you keep your cms.tpl as a fallback to all other CMS pages.

Comment: You don't need to override the cms controller anymore. This function is already written by default.

You can just create a page-ID.tpl in your themes/your-theme/templates/cms folder. Where ID is the cms page ID.

Answer (score 5):

## Update for prestashop 1.7

You don't need to override the cms controller anymore. This function is already written by default.

You can just create a `page-ID.tpl` in your `themes/your-theme/templates/cms` folder. Where ID is the cms page ID.

Comment: Hi, can it be done in the same way for cms category pages? I tried but not working.